# In makefile when I use inside bash function if statement it's throw error

Tags: bash, makefile

In makefile when I use inside bash function if statement it's  throw error

```
test : 
        foo() { if [[ "a" == "a" ]] ; then echo $$1 ; fi ; } ; foo "hello"
```

ERROR

> /bin/sh: 1: [[: not found

or with one [

```
test : 
        foo() { if [ "a" == "a" ] ; then echo $$1 ; fi ; } ; foo "hello"
```

ERROR

> /bin/sh: 1: [: a: unexpected operator

how I can use if statement in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using bash-specific features.  Make does not run the user's shell, it always uses `/bin/sh` by default.  On some systems, `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash` and your makefile will work.  On other systems, `/bin/sh` is a link to a POSIX shell such as `dash`.

POSIX does not allow `[[ ... ]]`, it only uses `[ ... ]`.  Additionally, in POSIX test equality is `=` and not `==`.  Only bash allows `==` as an extension.

So, if you want your command to be POSIX compliant it must be:

```
test : 
        foo() { if [ "a" = "a" ]; then echo $$1; fi; }; foo "hello"
```

Comment: "Always" is not accurate. See my reply on how to use a different shell.

Comment: I changed my statement to _always uses `/bin/sh` *by default*_ which is what I meant.  Thanks for the note.

Comment: Just FYI, not all systems supply `/bin/bash`.  I always prefer to simply write my recipes using POSIX sh capabilities, unless there's something that bash provides that is so useful it is justified in being a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `/bin/sh` is not `/bin/bash`. You need to set the shell in the Makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```